# Cocoa Bindings, should I just be using KVO instead?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, binding, cocoa-bindings

```
   [self.toolController bind:@"fillColor" toObject:self.fillColorWell withKeyPath:@"color" options:kvoDict];
```

versus

```
   [self.fillColorWell addObserver:self.toolController forKeyPath:@"color" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
```

and in my `toolController` class, in my implementation for `-observeValueForKeyPath:...`

```
if( [keyPath isEqual:@"color"] ) {
  self.fillColor = [object selectedObject];
}
```

Why would I pick one method over another to get the view to update to my model property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For bindings the only code you have to write is for the bind itself and thats it. With KVO you would have to write to code to handle the notification. If your binding UI and using Interface Builder then you don't need any code at all, which can be useful / a time saver for the simpler things + you don't have to generic write boiler plate code to keep things is sync which you would to respond to the KVO notification.

I have read otherwise, but its my understanding (and I did a quick new project to verify this) that bindings are in both directions. So say if you bind a text field to an NSString, the variable changes when the textfield gets updated and you can change the variable and the text field updates. KVO would only notify you on the object you have specified the update for.

Some say bad things about bindings and that its good that they aren't part of iOS etc etc, but they work for the simple cases and so maybe you should just go with bindings until you find case where they are inappropriate. But having said if you want at some point to take your code over to iOS...

Hope thats a good enough answer for you :)

Comment: Some bindings are one way, but to allow binding a readwrite property to a readonly one.  The readonly property can still expose a binding.   KVO is annoying because there's not automatic `removeObserver` the way there is an autoUnbinder and ARC these days, and not using `removeObserver` can lead to real problems.